# Can I use additional directories for grouping Android resources

Tags: android, android-layout

Creating of large Android project will lead to numerous layout files in res folder. 
Can I just group them by creating subfolders? Is is possible in Android?

For example what I have now:

```
res/
    /layout/
           /Some large list there
```

And what I wanted to achieve:

```
res/
   /layout/
      /subfolder1/
         /layout1.xml
         /view1.xml
         ......
      /subfolder2
         /another_layout.xml
         /another_view.xml
```

I tried to do this but got error of compilation. 
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **YES**, *but only if you're using Android Studio and thus the Gradle Build System*.

Btw: There's also a Thread on *code.google.com* discussing this issue ([Issue 2018: R.java should recognize resources in sub-directories](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2018)).
It has been closed by a Project Member with the following statement:

> Marking this as released. This is largely possible in the Gradle build
>   system as it exists today, and we won't be implementing this for other
>   build systems.

So how can you realise this in Android Studio? Here's how:

1. Right Click on your layout-folder --> New --> *Directory* --> Name it e.g. **subfolder1**
2. Right Click on **subfolder1** --> New --> *Android resource directory* (this may not be selectable to you in the first place, see the notes below)
3. Name it *layout*, *layout-land*, *layout-sw600dp* or whatever you want it just needs to be valid layout resource folder
4. Create more subfolders or layout-folders in your sub-dirs
5. Modify your `build.gradle` file like this:

---

```
android {
    // Other stuff
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                      '/src/main/res/layout/subfolder1',
                      '/src/main/res/layout/subfolder2',
                      '/src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
}
```

Result would look like this:

[image: sub directories in layout folder]

**Some things to note:**

- You may need to Sync Gradle in between, otherwise you won't be able
  to create a *"Android resource directory* in your subfolder
- If you're using the Android-View in Android Studio you won't be
  seeing your subfolders. I consider this as a bug which will be fixed,
  hopefully.
- This works for drawables and every other resource type as well

Answer (score 0):

no, you can not. What you can have is different folders for different screen density/size and language. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) some documentation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant. The android project structure is very restricted. see [Grouping Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes)